# About retrieving page name in index page

Tags: reactjs

Goal:
When you write url "https://react-router-with-params-aq6utk.stackblitz.i/test" I would like to display the page test.

Problem:
Is it possble to retrieve the value 'test' and use it at app.js?

Today it doesn't work.

Info:
*Newbie in reactjs

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-uaofyx?file=src%2FApp.js

---

app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { HomeComponent } from './Containers/HomeComponent';
import DashboardComponent from './Containers/DashboardComponent';
import ContactComponent from './Containers/ContactComponent';

import { Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
    };
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.id);
    console.log(this.props);

    if (this.props.id === 'test') {
      return (
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/test" exact component={ContactComponent} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route
              path="/dashboard/:id"
              render={(props) => (
                <DashboardComponent {...props} isAuthed={true} />
              )}
            />
            <Route path="" exact component={HomeComponent} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

export default App;
```

---

ContactComponent.js

```
import React from 'react';

export const ContactComponent = ({ value }) => {
  const name = 'CONTACT';
  return <h1>{name}</h1>;
};
```

---

DashboardComponent.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class DashboardComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(this.props.match.params.id);
  }

  render() {
    return <div>Hello from dashboard.. ffff</div>;
  }
}

export default DashboardComponent;
```

---

HomeComponent.js

```
import React from 'react';

export const HomeComponent = ({ value }) => {
  const name = 'rajesh';
  return <h1>{name}</h1>;
};
```

Comment: Hi, would you give feedback about my answer? thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with the implementaion of `Route`. also, you export the `ContactComponent` without `default` but you used it in `App.js` with the default import statement.

The working code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { HomeComponent } from './Containers/HomeComponent';
import DashboardComponent from './Containers/DashboardComponent';
import { ContactComponent } from './Containers/ContactComponent';

import { Switch, Route, Link, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/test" exact component={ContactComponent} />
          <Route
            path="/dashboard/:id"
            component={(props) => <DashboardComponent {...props} isAuthed={true} />}
          />
          <Route path="" exact component={HomeComponent} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

check the live version on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jjmixc?file=src/App.js)

##### Explanation:

If you export a variable with the default keyword, so you need to import it without `{}`

```
const first = 'first'
const second = 'second'

export first
export default second
```

Now in usage:

```
import second, {first} from 'myVariables';
```

Also, your route configuration with `react-router-dom` will look like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact={true} component={Home} />
    <Route path="/about" exact={true} component={About} />
    <Route path="/contact" exact={true} component={Contact} />
    // rest of the routes ...
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

**Note:** Your `App.js` component is the root component so there aren't any `props` with it.

Comment: Is it still possible to retrieve value 'test' in app.js? I need to have two separated return in relation to if else

Comment: implement your conditional block inside of the `<Switch>`  @What'sUP

Comment: I cannot retrieve the value 'test' in a variable. Do you have the possiblility to use stackblitz? It is easier to understand and it goes a pedagogical approach

Comment: the stackblitz version has changed, can you post the original codes? @What'sUP

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-uaofyx?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: here you are : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jjmixc?file=src/App.js  @What'sUP

Comment: 'if you want to access the test page, try to replace this.props.id with a truthy value'
Do you have sample about what you mean truthy value?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Comment: By evaluating an undefined value, your test route will never be reachable. you defined a props.id that doesn't exist so evaluating the condition always returns false!
 @What'sUP